# How do I register a protocol to work with my program?

Tags: python, protocols

I'd like my program to be summoned when a browser tries to open a page with the protocol "tf2emp://xxxxx".
The program will then have to download content based on the 5 digit number given in said protocol.
My program is written in python, and I'm using wx for the gui.

Comment: Protocol registration is operating system and browser dependent. Which operating system(s) are you looking to support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol) from Mozilla should help you register protocols for Mozilla Firefox on WIndows and Linux. Similar info exists for other browsers/platforms, Google is your friend. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a peek at Microsoft's page on the subject:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx